# Array Index out of bounds exception:Android

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

While iterating the two lists and  displaying the items in the layouts i m getting the Array Index out of bounds exception at the line below.How can we have a null check or a condition with which i wont get the error

```
   ParallelList<BaseItem> list = new ParallelList<BaseItem>(highlighted, normal);
    for (List<BaseItem> ints : list) {

      final BaseItem itemH = ints.get(0);


       if(!ints.get(1).equals(null) && ints.size()!=0){ // error here at this line
            final BaseItem itemn = ints.get(1);


         }
```

using the below parallellist for this

```
                 public class ParallelList<T> implements Iterable<List<T>> {

                 private final List<List<T>> lists;

                 public ParallelList(List<T>... lists) {
                 this.lists = new ArrayList<List<T>>(lists.length);
                 this.lists.addAll(Arrays.asList(lists));
          }

             public Iterator<List<T>> iterator() {
              return new Iterator<List<T>>() {
             private int loc = 0;

            public boolean hasNext() {
                boolean hasNext = false;
                for (List<T> list : lists) {
                    hasNext |= (loc < list.size());
                }
                return hasNext;
            }

            public List<T> next() {
                List<T> vals = new ArrayList<T>(lists.size());
                for (int i=0; i<lists.size(); i++) {
                    if(loc < lists.get(i).size()){
                       vals.add(lists.get(i).get(loc));
                    }
                  //  vals.add(loc < lists.get(i).size() ? lists.get(i).get(loc): null);
                }
                loc++;
                return vals;
            }

            public void remove() {
                for (List<T> list : lists) {
                    if (loc < list.size()) {
                        list.remove(loc);
                    }
                }
              }
              };
            }
           }
```

Error is here

```
          java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
          at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
          at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reverse the conditions. First make sure the size of the list is large enough (i.e. it has more than one element), and only then attempt to access the second element of the list :

```
if(ints.size() > 1 && ints.get(1) != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn it around:

```
   if(ints.size()!=0 && !ints.get(1).equals(null))
```

The && connection is evaluatef from left to right. So when the size is 0 then the left part is false already. The full && expression cannot be true regarless what !ints.get(1).equals(null) gets evaluated to. Therefore it will not be executed at all.

BTW, the first element has the index 0. You really want to use:

```
   if(ints.size()!=0 && !ints.get(0).equals(null))
```

or

```
   if(ints.size()<=2 && !ints.get(1).equals(null))
```

PS: Having a closer look at the error message, it turns out that the latter really fixes your problem. Size is actually 1 but you are accessing the second item with the index 1. (Again, first index is 0)

Answer (score 0):

You should try these conditions

```
if(!ints.isEmpty()){
final BaseItem itemH = ints.get(0);


       if( ints.size()>=1 && !ints.get(1).equals(null) ){ 
            final BaseItem itemn = ints.get(1);
}
}

     }
```

Comment: This will crash when `ints.size()==1`